# TeX4ebook handles accented characters incorrectly

Tags: unicode, spanish, tex4ebook

I'm trying `TeX4ebook` on the following minimal `LaTeX` file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\title{Título}
\author{Autor}
\date{Fecha}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\textquote{¡Hola, mundo!}
áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚüÜñÑ.

\end{document}
```

Accented characters appear in the epub file as á´aé´eí´ıó´oú´uÁ´AÉ´EÍ´IÓ´OÚ´UüÜñ˜nÑ˜N. Umlauts are fine.

[image: Here's a screenshot of the epub file from the Calibre viewer.]

Following the suggestions [on this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301733/tex4ebook-accents-displays-as-wrong-characters-only-produces-epub-2-0-no-3-0), I'm calling `tex4ebook` with the following options:

```
tex4ebook -t tex4ebook-test-spanish.tex "html5,charset=utf-8" " -cunihtf -utf8"
```

All messages from `tex4ebook` seem to be fine:

```
[STATUS]  tex4ebook: Conversion started
[STATUS]  tex4ebook: Input file: tex4ebook-test-spanish.tex
HTML Tidy for Linux version 5.6.0
[STATUS]  tex4ebook: Conversion finished
```

I'm using the `TeXLive` version that comes packaged with Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You definitely don't need to provide `"html5,charset=utf-8" " -cunihtf -utf8"` to `tex4ebook`, as it creates UTF-8 encoded documents by default. The `html5` option may even cause issues, as Epub 2 expects XHTML documents, not HTML 5. This shouldn't be a issue in most cases though.

It seems that the character decomposition is caused by Babel. You have two options:

- use LuaLaTeX for the compilation
- use an explicit call to the Fontenc package

Easiest for you should be to use LuaLaTeX. Try to add the `-l` option to your `tex4ebook` call:

```
tex4ebook -l -t tex4ebook-test-spanish.tex
```

If this doesn't work for your real document, you can add the Fontenc package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\title{Título}
\author{Autor}
\date{Fecha}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\textquote{¡Hola, mundo!}
áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚüÜñÑ.

\end{document}
```

You don't need the `-l` option in this case.

Either way, it should produce this result:

[image]

Comment: I tried the LuaLaTeX and the fontenc options (separately) and they both work like a charm. Thanks!